# Laravel relatives with sync method

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

I try to store my products id and related them to each other just like when you attach tags to the post. (basically just store id of products nothing more)

## Issue

when I try to save my product I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_relative_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `product_relative_id` from `product_relatives` where `product_id` = 46)
```

## Codes

`schema`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_relatives', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('relatives_id')->unsigned();
        });
        Schema::table('product_relatives', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
          $table->foreign('relatives_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }
```

`ProductRelative model`

```
class ProductRelative extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'product_relatives';

    public $fillable = ['product_id', 'relatives_id'];


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_relatives');
    }
}
```

`Product model`

```
public function relatives()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductRelative::class, 'product_relatives');
  }
```

`Store method`

```
//load other products in create page
public function create()
    {
        $relatives = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.create', compact('relatives'));
    }

//storing new product
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validation etc.
        $product->save();
        $product->relatives()->sync($request->relatives, false);
        return redirect()->route('products.show',$product->id);
    }
```

`blade`

```
{{ Form::label('relatives', 'Relative Products') }}
<select data-placeholder="Select a Relative product" class="form-control tagsselector" id="relatives" name="relatives[]" multiple="multiple">
  @foreach($relatives as $relative)
    <option value="{{ $relative->id }}">{{ $relative->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

## Question

Why do I get the error and how to solve it?

## UPDATE

I've changed my `product model` to the code below and it's working now.

```
public function relatives()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductRelative::class, 'product_relatives', 'product_id', 'relatives_id');
  }
```

## New Issue

Now that I can save my related products I have a hard time to return them in my view.

So far:

I added this code to my view function:

```
$relatives = ProductRelative::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
```

and added this code to my view:

```
@foreach($relatives as $relative)
  {{$relative}}
@endforeach
```

with that I can get result like:

```
{"id":3,"product_id":36,"relatives_id":2} {"id":5,"product_id":36,"relatives_id":25}
```

but when I change my blade code to `{{$relative->title}}` it does not return anything.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I changed my view codes to code below and it's working now:

```
$relatives = ProductRelative::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
    ->join('products','products.id', '=', 'relatives_id')->get();
```

Hope it helps.